# JQuery: .live() and trigger() not working together

Tags: jquery

```
  $('#id').bind('change',function() {
      //do something
    }).trigger('change');
```

it works fine. but if id2 has been generated by using AJAX

i am trying to use

```
$('#id2').live('change',function() {
  //do something
}).trigger('change');
```

But its not working. Can anybody help me please.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you write

```
$('#id2').live('change',function() {
  //do something
});
```

then you do this because `#id2` is *not created yet*. `trigger('change')` on the other hand immediately triggers an event. But if the element does not exist yet, calling it has no effect.

You need to call `trigger()` once the element is created:

```
$('#id2').trigger('change');
```

---

There is no need to use `live()` if `#id2` already exists. You can just use `bind()`.

Comment: #id2 is not created yet, so i have to use live(). is there any other solution to trigger?

Comment: *"you do this because #id2 is not created yet"* Well, you might use `live` even if the element already exists (in case you periodically replace it with something new with the same `id`). But I expect that **is* the OP's problem, because it works if the element already exists: http://jsbin.com/ipohe4

Comment: @Raj: That's Felix's point: You can't call *`trigger`* on an element that doesn't exist. `trigger` only works on existing elements.

Comment: @Raj, if `#id2` is not created yet, why are you trying to trigger an event on it? trigger the event when it is created (like in an ajax callback) and it'll work.

Comment: @Raj: See my update, call trigger when you create that element. @T.J. Crowder: True, if the element gets replaced... did not think about that.

Comment: @Jamiec - i am using two drop downs and one text box, first one is already created and selection based on SESSION, and 2nd one based on first drop down and storred SESSION, and third which is text box is based on both

Comment: @Raj: Maybe you should post your complete (better most relevant parts of your) code... I can tell you that `$('#id2').trigger('change');` definitely works if `#id2` does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trigger the change event in an ajax-complete function?